# Joomla 1.5 Article Meta Keywors and Description management

Tags: seo, joomla, components, joomla1.5, keyword

Thx for your time!

I am currenly using sh404SEF, and it has "Title and Metas" manager. This is pretty much what I need, the only problem is that if URLs are purged so are title and Metas and it does not have place for keywords. Here is screen shot of what it looks like http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/5624/sh404titlemetasmanager.jpg

**I am looking for a administrative component that will allow me to manage all the article keywords and descriptions in one place for multiple articles at a time.** The components needs to update the keywords and description for the actual articles in [#__content] table, and not an overload plug-in. I looked through extensions directory, did not find what I was looking for.

Comment: Alex: I sent you a message via boolcast.com regarding your closed PHP question.  I know this comment will probably be deleted but I dont know how else to inform you. ;-/

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at Scribe - http://scribeseo.com/

It's paid for but pretty good for SEO/meta etc.

Comment: I checked it out. All their services can be substituted with basic SEO knowledge and free extensions for the browser. Thx for trying.